# Create an audio file in C# (WP7)

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, audio

Does anyone know how to create an audio file (.wav, .mp3, etc.) in c#? Specifically for a windows phone 7.

Comment: Are you asking how to create an audio file on the windows phone 7 platform? How would an audio file be specific for a windows phone?

Comment: ..Do you want to use the build-in microphone for recording audio?

Comment: Sorry, I worded that poorly. I have a wp7 app (QuickNote) that lets users record audio notes and play them back. I use the microphone and save the raw audio data so I can play the audio back later. I need to be able to create an audio file so I can post it to my server and email it.

Comment: It's not poor wording, it's a lack of information

Answer (score 4):

When you are working with the microphone, you get a constantly increasing buffer (for the time of recording). The total byte array represents PCM contents when saved. So to say, that is the WAV file with missing header information. Here is a great blog post on how to add that header information:
http://damianblog.com/2011/02/07/storing-wp7-recorded-audio-as-wav-format-streams/

If you decide to convert the content to MP3, you will have to implement your own conversion layer since the OS itself (Windows Phone) lacks the capabilities to do this.